# Python lists into MySQL Database

Tags: python, mysql, list

I have a question and I am actually already struggling with the approach how to tackle it.
I have several lists.

```
name = ['name1','name2', 'name3']
id = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3']
created_at = ['created_at1', 'created_at2', 'created_at3']
```

The lists have always the same number of element.
What I want to do is write them into a MySql database that looks like this:

```
Name   ID    Created_at
name1  id1   created_at1
name2  id2   created_at2
name3  id3   created_at3
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use zip.

```
output = zip(name, id, created_at)
```

output: [('name1', 'id1', 'created_at1'), ('name2', 'id2', 'created_at2'), ('name3', 'id3', 'created_at3')]

Iterate through the output and insert into the database.

updated: Iterating through output:

```
for item in output:
    === Have to do mysql insert operation ===
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It looks really promising but I do not know how to then iterate through the items and put them in the database...

Comment: Here is the link for Mysql operations: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm. All the best!

Answer (score 1):

Iterating through multiple lists at the same time is what `zip` (and even better, `itertools.izip`) are for.

```
for each_name, each_id, each_created_at in itertools.izip(name, id, created_at):
    ... insert into db...
```

Comment: If you use `executemany()` it doesn't matter if you use `zip()` or `izip()`.